# Prolog-Parse XML which have the same tag name

Tags: xml, prolog, swi-prolog

Can someone help me with parsing an XML which contains the same tag names throughout the document.I have to find out the sibling and the child of each of the tags.

PS. I am provided with a SAX parser which converts the XML into a list.

```
X = [startTag('A'), startTag('A'), startTag('A'), endTag('A'), endTag('A'), startTag('A'), startTag('A'), endTag('A'), endTag(...)|...]
```

The above is how my list of XML tags looks like.

Below is my code for getting the sibling of a XML tag.

```
getLabel(Label,[endTag(Label),startTag(_,Y)|_],Y).
getLabel(Label,[endTag(Label)],0).
getLabel(Label,[endTag(Label),endTag(_)|_],0).
getLabel(Label,[_|T],X):-getLabel(Label,T,X).
```

It works fine in all scenarios except for the one mentioned here.
Can some please provide some idea so as to how I should parse this XML and get its children.

Comment: I don't get your approach to solve this. What is the meaning of the last parameter?  Where do you get the second parameter for `startTag`? `startTag(_,Y)|_],Y`

Comment: First, you should (re)build the syntax tree. You can do with a DCG, that make easy to match nested structures.